# Can the first key of partition key be a clustering key?

Tags: sql, database, cassandra, cql

With the below schema in Cassandra database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  stackoverflow_sorted_by_key_part_two (
      key_part_one      UUID,
      key_part_two      UUID,
      idempotence_key   int,
      data              TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY((key_part_one, idempotence_key), key_part_two)      
);
```

---

`(key_part_one, idempotence_key)` is a partition key &  `key_part_two`
is clustering key.

With the above schema, records are sorted(as part of table indexing) order by `key_part_two` in ascending order

---

But, for faster select query(with `WHERE key_part_one == "some_uuid"`), we want the records sorted(as part of table indexing) order by  `key_part_one`.

Does the below schema enhance the select query performance?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  stackoverflow_sorted_by_key_part_one (
      key_part_one      UUID,
      key_part_two      UUID,
      idempotence_key   int,
      data              TEXT,
      PRIMARY KEY((key_part_one, idempotence_key), key_part_two)      
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (key_part_one ASC);
```

---

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that - you can specify only clustering columns in the `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY`.  If column is part of partition key, it's not sortable - Cassandra applies the hash function to the value of this column (or columns if it's composite key), and use that hash (token) to find what node is responsible for that token.  And sorting by clustering column then happens inside the partition only.

P.S. Look through the first chapters of the "Cassandra: The definitive guide, 3rd edition" book that is [freely available from DataStax site](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) - it will help you with data modeling for Cassandra.

Comment: One more question: For table with just 3 columns (`key_part_one`, `key_part_two`, `data`) with clustering column as `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (key_part_one ASC)`....... Do we need to mention syntax as `PRIMARY KEY(key_part_two, key_part_one) `, where `key_part_two` becomes partition key

Comment: yes, if you're searching by at least `key_part_two`...

Comment: For table with one column(`some_maintenance_id`)  with `PRIMARY KEY(some_maintenance_id)`. Can we call `some_maintenance_id` as both partition key & clustering key?

Comment: no, you can't use the same column as both partition key & clustering column.  But you can create 2nd column that will be populated with the same content as first.

Comment: or rather, we don't need clustering column as it is one column. Because we don't need sorting as such, just hashing(column value) would suffice